# Only first of multiple PDO queries being executed?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm attempting to execute two separate `PDO` queries in a row. However, only one will execute correctly at a time. Whichever one comes first is the only one to correctly query the database and return any values. I've tried using var_dump to see  what they're returning, and the second PDO query returns "boolean false" and doesn't contain any information.

**Here is my code:**

```
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);

// make and execute query for client information
    $client_query = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM clients WHERE id=:ID');
    $client_query->execute(array('ID' => $client_id));
    $client_result = $client_query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    // set client information for captcha
    $this->client_name = $client_result['name'];
    $this->client_id = $client_result['id'];

    $client_query->closeCursor();

    // make and execute query for campaign information
    $campaign_query = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM campaigns WHERE id=:ID AND client_id=:CLIENT');
    $campaign_query->execute(array('ID' => $campaign_id, 'CLIENT' => $client_id));
    $campaign_result = $campaign_query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    // set campaign information for captcha
    $this->campaign = $campaign_result;
```

If I remove the parameters from the second query, they both execute successfully. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: Enable `PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING`.

Comment: I find it really strange that a prepared statement for an invalid SQL query runs successfully when you don't provide parameters... How are you verifying that both queries run successfully?

Comment: Either case, just use `$client_query->errorInfo();` after the execution of the query to check on any SQL errors. Also, `$client_query->execute()` will return `true` on execution success, or `false` otherwise.

Comment: I tried enabling PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING to no avail, and errorInfo() is returning an empty array.

Comment: Um, it should never return an `empty` array, it's always filled with three things, unless you are creating an object out of a static `::prepare()` call.

Comment: @dbf sorry not `empty`, it returns: `Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => )`

Comment: hm. I guess that $campaign_id should be $this->$campaign_id and $client_id should be $this->client_id in the parameters? I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld actually `$campaign_id` and `$client_id` are both parameters passed to the construct function, which all of this code is within.

Comment: @Jakemmarsh - what are the values of $campaign_id and $client_id then?

Comment: I found the source of my problem, embarrassing as it was. I posted it as my own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embarrassingly, all the code was correct (except for a small SQL syntax mistake that some of you caught). My problem was that the value for `$campaign_id` was greater than any values stored in the mySQL table, and so the query actually returned no results. So actually there was no problem with the queries, there were just no results to return for the second one. I appreciate all the answers and apologize for this sad oversight!

Answer (score 3):

Your SQL is invalid; change this:

```
SELECT * FROM campaigns WHERE id=:ID AND WHERE client_id=:CLIENT
```

to this:

```
SELECT * FROM campaigns WHERE id=:ID AND client_id=:CLIENT
```

Comment: I'm using execute() and then fetch(), which works correctly for just one parameterized query... is that incorrect?

Comment: No it is correct, however I just found the problem: your query syntax is invalid. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I have fixed my syntax, and the second query is still not working. I'll update my original post with the new code.

Answer (score 2):

As the [Errors and error handling](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php) chapter explains:

> PDO offers you a choice of 3 different error handling strategies

... and the default is `PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT`, that means: suppress all error messages and hope the developer doesn't forget to check if there were errors.

To sum up: you need to do error checking.

Comment: I changed the error mode for the database and still no results. I updated my code in the original post.

Comment: I see you've chosen `PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING` but I don't know whether your system is configured to print warnings. Additionally, I cannot see code to read back error messages.

Comment: I was using `print_r($db->errorInfo());` or `print_r($campaign_query->errorInfo());` to try and print the error, but they both output `Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => )`

Answer (score 1):

At a first glance... I would change your code to: (Use colons in the arrays as well and there were duplicates of the reseverd keyword "where" in the second sql-statement). I would exception instead of warning- and then catch exception when necessary.

```
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

// make and execute query for client information
$client_query = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM clients WHERE id=:ID');
$client_query->execute(array(':ID' => $client_id));
$client_result = $client_query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// set client information for captcha
$this->client_name = $client_result['name'];
$this->client_id = $client_result['id'];

$client_query->closeCursor();

// make and execute query for campaign information
$campaign_query = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM campaigns WHERE id=:ID AND client_id=:CLIENT');
$campaign_query->execute(array(':ID' => $campaign_id, ':CLIENT' => $client_id));
$campaign_result = $campaign_query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

// set campaign information for captcha
$this->campaign = $campaign_result;
```

You could do like above when trying to retrieve values, BUT consider using JOINS instead like this:

```
SELECT * FROM clients cls
LEFT JOIN campaigns cas ON (cls.id = cas.client_id)
WHERE cas.id=:ID
```

Comment: Colons in parameter arrays are optional.

Comment: I fixed my SQL syntax, still not working. I updated my code in the original post.